# Sobel Operator works only for small images

Tags: java, image-processing

The idea for this sobel operator is to first place value of each pixel into the array and then to separate these values into three arrays, one for each RGB component. The arrays containing the values of RGB components are each then transformed and then combined into final array for generating the output image.

However, it appears that it works well only for smaller images about the size of 350x350 px and I don't know why.

I think that the problem is in the scansize parameter for getRGB() and setRGB(), since it works when I hardcore the value of the image height for scansize instead of the image width.

```
public class Sobel {


private BufferedImage image;

public Sobel(BufferedImage image)
{
    this.image = image;
}

public BufferedImage process()
{

    double  A[][], B[][], Ar[][], Br[][], Ag[][], Bg[][], Ab[][], Bb[][], G[][], Gr[][], Gg[][], Gb[][];
    BufferedImage inImg =  image;
    int width = inImg.getWidth();   
    int height = inImg.getHeight();   
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];   

    // RGB channels of the image
    int[][] red = new int[width][height];
    int[][] green = new int[width][height];
    int[][] blue = new int[width][height];

    try {
        image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    int counter = 0;   

    for(int i = 0 ; i < width ; i++ )   
    {   
        for(int j = 0 ; j < height ; j++ )   
        {   
            // get color of each pixel and separate it in the RGB components
            Color c = new Color(pixels[counter]);
            red[i][j] = c.getRed();
            green[i][j] = c.getGreen();
            blue[i][j] = c.getBlue();
            counter = counter + 1;   
        }              
    }   

// Arrays for RGB values (Ar, Br, Ag, Bg, Ab, Bb) which are than combined into final array for generating processed image  
A = new double[width][height];   
B = new double[width][height];
Ar = new double[width][height];   
Br = new double[width][height]; 
Ag = new double[width][height];   
Bg = new double[width][height];
Ab = new double[width][height];   
Bb = new double[width][height]; 
G  = new double[width][height];
Gr  = new double[width][height];
Gg  = new double[width][height];
Gb  = new double[width][height];


/**
 *  Transform pixel p of each RGB channel
 *  p = sqrt(A^2 + B^2),
 *  where A = (p3 + 2*p4 + p5) - (p1 + 2*p8 + p7)
 *   and  B = (p1 + 2*p2 + p3) - (p7 + 2*p6 + p5)
 *  
 *      Pixel p
 * 
 *      p1 p2 p3
 *      p8 p  p4
 *      p7 p6 p5
 */
for (int i=0; i<width; i++) {   
  for (int j=0; j<height; j++) {   
    if (i==0 || i==width-1 || j==0 || j==height-1)   
      A[i][j] = B[i][j] = G[i][j] = Ar[i][j] = Br[i][j] = Gr[i][j] = Ag[i][j] = Bg[i][j] = Gg[i][j] = Ab[i][j] = Bb[i][j] = Gb[i][j] = 0; // Image boundary cleared   
    else
    {   
        // RED CHANNEL
        Ar[i][j] = red[i-1][j+1] + 2*red[i][j+1] + red[i+1][j+1] - red[i-1][j-1] - 2*red[i][j-1] - red[i+1][j-1];   
        Br[i][j] = red[i-1][j-1] + 2*red[i-1][j] + red[i-1][j+1] - red[i+1][j-1] - 2*red[i+1][j] - red[i+1][j+1];

        Gr[i][j] = Math.sqrt(Ar[i][j]*Ar[i][j] + Br[i][j]*Br[i][j]);

        // GREEN CHANNEL
        Ag[i][j] = green[i-1][j+1] + 2*green[i][j+1] + green[i+1][j+1] - green[i-1][j-1] - 2*green[i][j-1] - green[i+1][j-1];   
        Bg[i][j] = green[i-1][j-1] + 2*green[i-1][j] + green[i-1][j+1] - green[i+1][j-1] - 2*green[i+1][j] - green[i+1][j+1];

        Gg[i][j] = Math.sqrt(Ag[i][j]*Ag[i][j] + Bg[i][j]*Bg[i][j]);

        // BLUE CHANNEL
        Ab[i][j] = blue[i-1][j+1] + 2*blue[i][j+1] + blue[i+1][j+1] - blue[i-1][j-1] - 2*blue[i][j-1] - blue[i+1][j-1];   
        Bb[i][j] = blue[i-1][j-1] + 2*blue[i-1][j] + blue[i-1][j+1] - blue[i+1][j-1] - 2*blue[i+1][j] - blue[i+1][j+1];
        //System.out.println(output[i][j]);

        Gb[i][j] = Math.sqrt(Ab[i][j]*Ab[i][j] + Bb[i][j]*Bb[i][j]);

        //if((int)Gg[i][j] > 255) System.out.println("GREEN : " + Gg[i][j] + " ~ " + (int)Gg[i][j] + "\n" + green[i-1][j+1] + " " + green[i][j+1] + " " + green[i+1][j+1] + " " + green[i-1][j-1] + " " + green[i][j-1] + " " + green[i+1][j-1] + " " + green[i-1][j-1] + " " + green[i-1][j] + " " + green[i-1][j+1] + " " +  green[i+1][j] + " " + green[i+1][j] + " " + green[i+1][j+1]);
        if((int)Gg[i][j] > 255) {Gg[i][j] = 255; }
        if((int)Gb[i][j] > 255) {Gb[i][j] = 255; }
        if((int)Gr[i][j] > 255) {Gr[i][j] = 255; }


        G[i][j] = new Color((int)Gr[i][j], (int)Gg[i][j], (int)Gb[i][j]).getRGB();

    }   
  }   
}   
counter = 0;   
for(int ii = 0 ; ii < width ; ii++ )   
{   
    for(int jj = 0 ; jj < height ; jj++ )   
    {                  
        pixels[counter] = (int)G[ii][jj];   
        counter = counter + 1;   
    }              
}

BufferedImage outImg = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

System.out.println("pixels.length = " + pixels.length + "; Image size: " + outImg.getHeight() + "x" + outImg.getWidth());


//outImg.getRaster().setPixels(0,0,width,height,pixels);   
outImg.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);

return outImg;
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? OutOfMemoryException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images are stored in row-major format.

So the outer loop should be iterating over rows (there should be `height` iterations), and the inner loop should be iterating over the pixels in each row (there should be `width` iterations). So basically you need to swap `width` and `height` everywhere except on the calls to `getRGB`/`setRGB`.

Comment: Wow! I've changed the height and width in for loops and arrays and it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey, I'm just wondering what do you think of the result for this sobel operator if you tried it?

Comment: @ivandj: I didn't try it, I just looked at the code quickly. Note for further questions: you should have described what didn't work ("*the code executes properly, but the output looks weird*"; if possible post the output image along with the question), and you should perhaps have tried it on more images so that you could have given a more accurate description of what didn't work: the actual problem came from the aspect ratio, not the absolute size of the image.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get the good result using javacv which internally uses opencv

```
  IplImage iploriginal = IplImage.createFrom(originalBufferedImg);

  IplImage srcimg = IplImage.create(iploriginal.width(),iploriginal.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

  IplImage destimg = IplImage.create(iploriginal.width(),iploriginal.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

  cvCvtColor(iploriginal, srcimg, CV_BGR2GRAY);

  cvSmooth(srcimg, destimg, CV_BLUR,9, 9, 2, 2);

  cvSobel(srcimg, destimg,0,1,3);

  BufferedImage img=destimg.getBufferedImage();
```